# why is my class method not updating the attribute?

Tags: python, class, pygame, attributes

I'm trying to make a sprite that moves down at a constant pace, using pygame and random. But unfortunately, the sprite just stays in one place. 
The issue is the method itemMover(). It does not update the value of the attribute for the instance (debris1, at the bottom), so every time, straight after the y value gets increased by the speed value it gets reset to the original value... which causes the sprite to just standstill. 
I don't know why it isn't updating the attribute.

```
import pygame
import random

# variables
mainWindow = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
posX = random.randint(0,800)
posY = 0
#speedXRight = 0.5
#speedXLeft = -0.5
# images

sprite = pygame.image.load("rockred.png")
xval = random.randint(50, 750)
ypos = 0
yspeed = 0.5

class item:
    def __init__(self, xpos, ypos, yspeed):
        self.xpos = xpos
        self.ypos = ypos
        self.yspeed = yspeed

    # below method not working as intended

    def itemMover(self, win, val):
        ############HELP HERE
        print(self.ypos)
        self.ypos += self.yspeed
        ############HELP HERE
        print(self.xpos, self.ypos)
        win.blit(val, (self.xpos, self.ypos))
mainLoop = True
while mainLoop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            mainLoop = False
            #keycode.Main = False
    debris1 = item(xval, 0, 0.5)
    debris1.itemMover(mainWindow, sprite)
    pygame.display.update()
```

output:

```
0
167 0.5
0
167 0.5
0
167 0.5
0
167 0.5
0
167 0.5
0
167 0.5
0
167 0.5
0
167 0.5
```

also a window with a  sprite which stays still.

Comment: Looks like the code is behaving as expected. You're redefining `debris1 = item(xval, 0, 0.5)` on every loop, resetting the `ypos` every loop. 

Try defining `debris1` outside of your loop and then calling `debris1.itemMover(mainWindow, sprite)` inside the loop.

Comment: The issue has been answered already, but I will comment on something else. You said that you are creating a sprite, but you are not taking advantage of the `pygame.sprite.Sprite` class. You should since it is very helpful. If you do start using the sprite class, then you should also rename your itemMover() method to update() so you can use `pygame.sprite.Group()`s too (though you would have to change the method to get rid of the parameters since `update()` takes no parameters.  The built in Sprite stuff in pygame is pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the method `itemMover` would work, but you recreate the object `debris1` continuously in the loop. Hence the object starts at the begin in each frame. 
Create the object before the application loop and move the object in the loop.
Further more you have to clear the display by [`pygame.Surface.fill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill), before you draw the object:

```py
debris1 = item(xval, 0, 0.5)

mainLoop = True
while mainLoop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            mainLoop = False

    mainWindow.fill(0)
    debris1.itemMover(mainWindow, sprite)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that each time on the loop , you re create the object debrise1 with ypos=0 and yspeed=0.5 , so when you execute the method itemMover() it will always display the same changes , what you have to do is to create the object out of the loop , and what should be inside the loop is the methode itemMover() only , like this :

```
mainLoop = True
debris1 = item(xval, 0, 0.5)

while mainLoop:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        mainLoop = False
        #keycode.Main = False
debris1.itemMover(mainWindow, sprite)
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 its because i never worked with pygame so i dont know about that , what i understood was the source of your problem anyway